# meteor session not working with html5 video

Tags: coffeescript, html5-video, meteor

I'm trying to use meteor to manipulate a set of custom html5 video controls. My template code consists entirely of the following:

```
Template.video.created = ->
  Session.set 'videoPlaying', false

Template.video.events
  'click .video-button-play': ->
    video = $('video')[0]
    if video.paused then video.play() else video.pause()
    Session.set 'videoPlaying', not video.paused

Template.video.helpers
  isPlaying: ->
    true
```

The relevant html is as follows:

```
<div class="video-button video-button-play">
  {{#if isPlaying}}
    <i class="icon-pause"></i>
  {{else}}
    <i class="icon-play"></i>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

The above works in that the video stops and starts at the correct times and if I query the session data from the console it works. However, the moment I read the session data from the helper, everything goes to hell - some clicks result in nothing, some restart the video, others just play the audio. What's particularly wild is that even logging the session like:

```
Template.video.helpers
  isPlaying: ->
    console.log Session.get('videoPlaying')
    true
```

results in the same problem.

**SOLUTION:** I tried using preserve and placing the video in a constant region (thanks skeetmtp) and found that using a constant region was the best solution as it allowed me to continue using a poster with the video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor is rebuilding the entire "video" template whenever videoPlaying is changing, I guess your custom html5 video is inside this template. 
You should try either (if possible)

- Put it in a separate template
- Use a constant region around your custom html : http://docs.meteor.com/#constant
- Or use a preserve : http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve

Without having more information about your html code (in particular the custom video controls),  I cannot help you more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll give that a try now. I just added a link to some demo code at the end of my question.

Comment: `Template.video.preserve ['video']` seems to fix the issue, however I had to remove the poster, which is unfortunate.